# Twilio AccessToken using PHP not working

Tags: php, python, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I'm trying to generate a server-side Twilio Programable voice access token in PHP for use with a Swift iPhone app, but it's coming out too short and fails when registering for push notifications in the app.

Error is "Unauthorized answer from a service. Notification exception during registration: TNException: Couldn't create registration"

I can make the token OK in Python with the code from the quickstart

```
@app.route('/accessToken', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def token():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
  api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
  push_credential_sid = os.environ.get("PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID",     PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID)
  app_sid = os.environ.get("APP_SID", APP_SID)

  grant = VoiceGrant(
    push_credential_sid=push_credential_sid,
    outgoing_application_sid=app_sid
  )

  token = AccessToken(account_sid, api_key, api_key_secret,IDENTITY)
  token.add_grant(grant)

  return str(token)
```

But in converting to PHP something is going wrong - this code throws no errors and makes a token but it's 550 characters long instead of 570 and, as I say, fails to register when used.

The variables are all the same, and I've checked they're all there.

```
$token = new AccessToken(
    $twilioAccountSid,
    $twilioApiKey,
    $twilioApiSecret,
    3000,
    $identity
);

// Create Voice grant
$VoiceGrant = new VoiceGrant();
$VoiceGrant->setOutgoingApplicationSid($appSid);
$VoiceGrant->setPushCredentialSid($pushCredentialSid);

// Add grant to token
$token->addGrant($VoiceGrant);

// echo token
echo $token;
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you enter the token you get in the [debugger here](https://jwt.io/) and, obscuring any identifying information, post the result here? There's probably something missing, even though your code looks ok, it's just hard to tell.

Comment: I think that debugger helped fix it. It was the identity that was missing. If you put that as the answer I'll accept - also THANKS

Comment: Thanks! I've added an answer. It looked as though you were passing the identity, but I'm guessing `$identity` wasn't set properly elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @JonathanPlackett I am also facing this issue could you help me. Please share your mail id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best thing to do in this situation is to make sure that you have added all the grants required to the Access Token.

To do this, copy and paste your generated token into the [debugger here](http://jwt.io/). If you see a grant or section of a grant like identity missing, then make sure that you are properly passing that to your function.

Comment: I'm still getting the error although I'm getting the grants correctly in jwt.io..

"grants": {
    "video": {
      "room": "room-asdasdasd"
    }
  }

any hope to get it fixed ?

Comment: It would be best to create a new question and explain what you’re doing and the error you are getting.